# Samba share security changes: read-only and IP/MAC restrictions

Tags: security, ip, samba, readonly, mac-address

I have a samba share and I want to make some changes for security. Today everybody can read and write my files. It's not safe. I'd like to do the these things:

1- set up for everybody just read files

2- set and allow just to people with their IPs & Mac Address allowed to write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give only read permission and not write permission, open up your configuration file, the path to which is `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Inside this file, move down to the share name of your directory.
Now there must be an option *write list*. Either comment this or remove this option. This will now not allow anyone to write. To give read permissions, use these 2 options -

```
brosweable=yes
valid users=User1 user2 user3
```

Now to allow only hosts from particular IP addresses, use option *hosts allow*.

```
hosts allow=IP_of_host.
```

For example, if share name of your directory is *abc*, then your configuration for this file should like this:

```
[abc]
path=/abc
browseable=yes
valid users=john mike
hosts allow=127.0.0.0/24     // it must be IP of hosts you want to allow
```

Save your configuration file, enable service samba on firewall, and restart services *smb nmb* .

Comment: I'd recommend `read only = yes` be added as an explicit instruction too the share definition.

Comment: It would definitely be helpful adding that option. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I need specific ips and macs to write and not just read.

Comment: In write list option mention names of people whom you want to give write permission, and you'll need to provide credentials to the client to give write permission.